# Python regex negative lookbehind not failing match

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a regex to match phone numbers. One of the problems I've encountered is that some postcodes look like phone numbers. For example, in Brazil, postcodes look like this:

```
30.160-0131
```

So a simple regex will capture them as false positives:

```
In [63]: re.search(r"(?P<phone>\d+\.\d+-\d+)", "30.160-0131")
Out[63]: <_sre.SRE_Match at 0x102150990>
```

Luckily, such postcodes often come with a prefix which generally means "postcode", like this:

```
CEP 30.160-0131
```

So, if you see CEP in front of something that looks like a phone number, then it's not a phone number - it's a postcode. I've been trying to write a regex to capture that using [negative lookbehind](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), but it's not working. It still matches:

```
In [62]: re.search(r"(?<!CEP )(\d+\.\d+-\d+)", "CEP 30.160-0131")
Out[62]: <_sre.SRE_Match at 0x102150eb8>
```

Why does it still match, and how can I get the negative look-behind to fail the match?

Comment: Because part of it *can* be matched: http://regex101.com/r/aU4fV4/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid negative lookaheads if you allow the matching of those postcodes, and still extract only the phone numbers:

```
m = re.search(r"CEP \d+\.\d+-\d+|(\d+\.\d+-\d+)", s)
```

And then check if you got something in `m.group(1)` for the phone numbers.

---

Little demo with `re.findall`:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "There is a CEP 30.160-0131 and a  30.160-0132 in that sentence, which repeats itself like there is a CEP 30.160-0131 and a  30.160-0132 in that sentence."
>>> m = re.findall(r"CEP \d+\.\d+-\d+|(\d+\.\d+-\d+)", s)
>>> print(m)
['', '30.160-0132', '', '30.160-0132']
```

And from there, you can filter out the empty strings.

Comment: @misha Having no access to lookbehind in the code you usually use helps with that ;)

Answer (score 3):

The expression matches because you are not doing anything to anchor the number. For example:

```
"CEP 11.213-132"
```

will match `1.213-132` since it does not immediately follow `CEP`. But you can force a whitespace, or start of line anchor, to be right before the first digit:

```
re.search(r"(?<!CEP)(?:\s+|^)(\d+\.\d+-\d+)", s)
```

Comment: But then that won't match anything without the prefix, e.g. `re.search(r"(?<!CEP)\s+(\d+\.\d+-\d+)", "30.160-0131")` will return `None`.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution worked well, but I ended up going with @Jerry 's idea, since it's simpler and easier (for me) to understand.